# Wordpress Search Regex plugin breaks when I search

Tags: search-regex

The plugin installed correctly, and presents me with the query UI.  However, when I click search, I get a server error from Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

After tailing the server logs, I discovered the following error:

`[27-Jun-2016 22:39:56 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method SearchRegex::base_url() in /dom5181/wp-content/plugins/search-regex/view/results.php on line 26`

After commenting out the code in line 26 in the manner described [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/i-cannot-search-anything):

`<img src="<?php //echo plugins_url( '/images/small.gif', $this->base_url() ); ?>" style="display: none" alt="pre"/>`

Everything worked perfectly.